# Doze Mode issue with setAlarmClock() in AndroidAlarmManager Plugin

Tags: flutter, alarmmanager

Im facing an issue with alarms that androidAlarmManager never handle over doze mode even i used setAlarmClock() in my Flutter android app

Android Document says:"Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire."

Also i checked the plugin codes in android_alarm_manager-0.4.5 17 version,
with parameters ( wakeup: true, rescheduleOnReboot: true, alarmClock: true), AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot() func is returning setAlarmClock() with RTC_WAKEUP clock from native side.

Below you can find how im calling oneShot();

```
AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration(milliseconds: nextAlarmTimeInMilliseconds), item.id, _notificationCallBack,
rescheduleOnReboot: true,
alarmClock: true );
```

When first alarm goes off then second alarm set with the same id as oneShot().. it goes on and on..

Everythings seems working when phone awake however when phone enter doze mode, alarms not firing on exact time. Whenever the phone exit doze mode by moved or touched by someone, alarms are firing with delay.

Do you have any idea what might cause it?